# Sql Server 2014 Setup Stuck on Feature Selection

Tags: sql-server, sql, specifications

I think this problem is due to windows 10 bug due to which we can't click anywhere and this forum should be suitable for it. I am installing SQL server 2014 on my other PC which has little specifications as follows;

- 4 Gb RAM
- 0.8 to 0.1 Ghz core m processor
- 128 Gb SSD (3 Gb remaning)

While I install the SQL server 2014, It first takes too much time to load setup. When it loads the setup it gives `Error 0x8024402` on product update;

[image: <code>Error 0x8024402</code> on product update]

But I can still click on next and ignore this error. After Installing Setup files and Install Rules I can't click anywhere on the window during Feature Selection which is the main problem;

[image: Feature Selection]

Is this problem due to;

- I ignored `Error 0x8024402`
- My PC specs are low
- A bug in the SQL Server 2014 Setup

How I can overcome the problem due to which I can't click anywhere on the window during Feature Selection? Can I use SQL Server 2012 with Visual Studio 2017? I think there will be no such problem in SQL server 2012.

**Update:**

Just found more system specification that might help further in understanding the problem;

[image: System Specifications]

Comment: Ignore SQL server 2012 in the first picture as I took it from the internet, it's 2014, but the error was the same.

Comment: OS version? What about microsoft support, did you try contacting them? Not enough information to really figure out what could be wrong

Comment: @Vijay I updated the question, are you asking for OS build? How I can get Microsoft support. Is there any forum where I can post my question? Let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: Hmm, if you suspect only the UI, try a [command line install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score -1):

1. Try installing standalone installer of Microsoft Edge
   e.g latest edge https://www.techspot.com/downloads/7158-microsoft-edge.html
2. turn off the Antivirus(any antivirus you have)
3. Run SQL Server Setup As an Administrator.Your problem will be resolved

Comment: Please indicate how using edge will resolve this issue. And I've installed SQL server plenty of times with an antivirus enabled. Also, why not provide a link to Microsoft's website for edge?

Comment: It was a RAM issue, I wasn't able to install the 2014 version due to low specification of laptop. On another laptop, it was easily installed.

Comment: @spikey_richie dear i just googled for standalone so what i found i just added as an option further more regarding your first question you can read 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055456/kb4055456-incompletely-installed-error-on-feature-selection-page-when

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil Good dear, But sql server feature selection also freezes in Windows 10, version 20H2 if not updated.